# How to convert the text into vector using word2vec embedding?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

Suppose I have a dataframe shown below:

|Text

|Storm in RI worse than last hurricane

|Green Line derailment in Chicago

|MEG issues Hazardous Weather Outlook

I created word2vec model using below code:

```
def sent_to_words(sentences):
    for sentence in sentences:
        yield(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(str(sentence), deacc=True))

text_data = sent_to_words(df['Text'])
w2v_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(text_data, size=100, min_count=1, window=5, iter=50)
```

now how I will convert the text present in the 'Text' column to vectors using this word2vec model?

Answer (score 1):

Word2Vec models can only map words to vectors, so, as @metalrt mentioned, you have to use a function over the set of word vectors to convert them to a single sentence vector. A good baseline is to compute the mean of the word vectors:

```
import numpy as np

df["Text"].apply(lambda text: np.mean([w2v_model.wv[word] for word in text.split() if word in w2v_model.wv]))
```

The example above implements very simple tokenization by whitespace characters. You can also use `spacy` library to implement better tokenization:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

df["Text"].apply(lambda text: np.mean([self.keyed_vectors[token.text] for token in nlp.pipe(text) if not token.is_punct and token.text in self.keyed_vectors]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get generated word embeddings by

```
w2v_model.wv
```

you can get word embeddings of a specific word by

```
w2v_model.wv['word']
```

Comment: Yeah, by this we can get the embedding of a particular word. what I am asking is how I can get the vector for complete text. For ex: I want to get the vector representaion of text  'Storm in RI worse than last hurricane'.

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this. You can iterate through your corpus and decide the sentence with the largest word count.(named max_word_count) Then, you can generate sentence embeddings with the size of (the length of word_embedding size) *(max_word_count). Then you can concatenate word embeddings, having zeros at the end for the shorter sentences.
Another option is you can average for embeddings in a sentence. But please keep in mind that by doing this you can lose the word order.