# Word2Vec empty word not in vocabulary

Tags: python, word2vec

I'm currently required to work on a multilingual text classification model where I have to classify whether two sentences in two languages are semantically similar. I'm also required to use Word2Vec for word embedding.

I am able to generate the word embedding using Word2Vec, however, when I'm trying to convert my sentences to vectors with a method similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71847207/13328625). I get an error saying

> KeyError: "word '' not in vocabulary"

Here is my code snippet

```py
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
tokenized_text_data = [nltk.word_tokenize(sub) for sub in concatenated_text]

model = Word2Vec(sentences=tokenized_text_data, min_count=1)

# Error happens here
train_vectors = [model.wv[re.split(" |;", row)] for row in concatenated_text]
```

For context, concatenated_text is the sentences from two languages concatenated together with semi-colon as the delimiter. Hence, why the function `re.split(" |;")`.

I guess the important thing now is to understand why the error is telling me that an empty string `''` is not in the vocabulary.

I did not provide the sentences cause the dataset is too big and I can't seem to find which word of which sentence is producing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was because of the delimiter that I concatenated myself all along. There are other semicolons in the sentence dataset, and with how `re.split(" |;")` works, it will split the sentence such as `ice cream ; bread ; milk` into a list of `['ice', 'cream', '', '', 'bread', '', '', 'milk']`. Hence why the error `word '' not in vocabulary`.

I hope this would benefit someone in the future!

Comment: Most generally, people should remember: such a `KeyError` can be trusted. It means that what you're asking for isn't in the model, either because (a) it wasn't in training texts at all; or (b) wasn't there at least `min_count` times. If you're asking for something that isn't there you expected, you're mistaken either (a) about what was in the training data, for example if you somehow cut-off the corpus early or mis-tokenized it to remove what you expected; or (b) about what you're asking-for, as here, where using 2 different tokenizations means different (empty) tokens are there the 2nd time.

Comment: Totally agree, perhaps better text preprocessing could also help in certain situations